# Using cd command over bash

Tags: bash

I faced some commands like this:

```
cd /usr/local/src/netqmail-1.06

make setup check
```

How can I run them over bash script?

Is it right way? How can I correct it?

```
make /usr/local/src/netqmail-1.06 setup && make /usr/local/src/netqmail-1.06 check
```

**UPDATE:**

How is possible to do these ones?

```
cd /usr/local/src/
cp a b c ../d
```

Comment: `cd /usr/local/src/netqmail-1.06 && make setup check`??

Comment: I thought this is not possible or not recommended to use `cd` in bash

Comment: These constructs are rather common, and I don't see any issues here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. To solve problem involved `make`, you could do something like

   ```
   cd /usr/local/src/netqmail-1.06 && make setup check
   ```
2. To solve problem involved `cp`, you could do something similarly

   ```
   cd /usr/local/src/ && cp a b c ../d
   ```

Comment: @MortezaLSC Absolutely. Acutally, `cd` is a bash built-in command.

Comment: Thanks... So this is simpler than I thought... :)